# Can't run Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, eclipse-luna

I am new to Java world and I trying to setup Eclipse Luna so i can start using it.
I have installed JDK 11.0.12 and Eclipse Luna but when I run Eclipse, from the workspace log file i can see the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.stylesheets.StyleSheet cannot be found 
 by org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.100.v20140424-2042
```

I have made some google research but without success. Any suggestion?

Comment: Eclipse Luna is 7 years and 16 releases old and won't run with Java 11, use the current Eclipse 2021-06

Answer (score 2):

Luna is ages old. You are attempting to run Luna on JDK `11`, which is not compatible:

- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1089288/

You can downgrade your JDK and run Luna on that, if using Luna is unavoidable.

---

I am not sure how you did some research and did not find this information, if you copypaste your error message into Google, then the linked thread is literally the first result.

Comment: perhaps he not copy pasting the error message

Comment: Perhaps that might have been a sensible thing to do.

Comment: eclipse Luna is over 7 years old, it requires OpenJDK 8 to run it btw.